# How do I add the company field in Prestashop 1.7.x to the Create Account form

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I'm new in Prestashop. I need to have the Company field in the Create Form (for new customers). The Company field can be seen when an existing customer logs in and updates their address.

So far, the tutorials I've seen are all about adding a customer, which is not what I need,

Answer (score 1):

From the backend, you have control whether or not the Company is displayed.

```
Shop Parameters > Customer Settings > Enable B2B Mode = Yes
```

This will display the Company field in the Create Account form